# Filter Array of Objects with NSPredicate based on NSInteger property in super class

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate, kvc

I've got the following setup:

```
@interface Item : NSObject {
    NSInteger *item_id;
    NSString *title;
    UIImage *item_icon;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger *item_id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *item_icon;

- (NSString *)path;

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionairy;

@end
```

And

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Item.h"

@interface Category : Item {

}

- (NSString *)path;

@end
```

I've got an array with Category instances (called 'categories') that I'd like to take a single item out based on it's item_id. Here is the code I use for that:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"item_id == %d", 1]; 
NSArray *filteredArray = [categories filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

This leads to the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is
>   not key value coding-compliant for the key item_id.'

How can I fix this and what am I doing wrong? the properties are synthesized and I can acces and set the item_id property successfully on Category instances.

Comment: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"item_id == 1"]; 
NSArray *filteredArray = [categories filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

Comment: @Manohar the 1, is not static, it's actually a NSInteger which is variable, I left the setting of the variable outside the example since it should not affect the question or the answer. Even though I gave your solution a try, and it gives the same error

Comment: Have a look at to my answer

Comment: Are you sure that you want the `item_id` property as a *pointer*? `NSInteger` is not an object, so perhaps you want just `NSInteger item_id`.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR that fixed it. Not sure why I added that as a pointer (3 years ago). Thanks! Make sure you add an answer so I can mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared the `item_id` property as a *pointer*. But `NSInteger` is a scalar type (32-bit or 64-bit integer), so you should declare it as

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger item_id;
```

*Remark:* Starting with the LLVM 4.0 compiler (Xcode 4.4), both `@synthesize` and the instance variables are generated automatically.

Comment: How to use title in place item_id, for me crashing if I am using any property?

Comment: @Sandy: You better ask your own question to that you can provide all necessary information.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing is that NSArray cannot contain primitive type of objects like 1, 2, 3. But, does contain object. So, when you create a predicate you should create it in the same way as such that it takes object. The above predicate should be reformed to something like this to work;

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"item_id == %@", @(1)];
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it still gives me the exact same error.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",yourIntVariable];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"item_id == %@", str]; 
NSArray *filteredArray = [categories filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: This does not work. The issue is elsewhere: "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key item_id." as mentioned in the question. The predicate looks correct to me as well, hence my confusion. When filtering on another items, which isn't inherited from the base class, it works perfectly. I believe the issue is in the KVC setup, not in the Predicate. But that's more a educated guess.